# ARCore Generate 3D object from URL and augment image

Tags: android, arcore

I'm having problem generating 3D object from URL using the following code, it's giving me an error which i'm not sure what it is. It will be awesome if anyone can point out what is wrong with the code

I followed tutorial from Google: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables. But have to modify a bit because of syntax error.

(1)The following code is supposed to generate the 3D object from URL - ASSET_URL (i have tested this URL which works).

```
    private AugmentedImage image;
    private CompletableFuture<ModelRenderable> modelRenderable;

        modelRenderable =
                ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(context, RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
                        context,
                        Uri.parse(ASSET_URL),
                        RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2)
                        .setScale(0.5f)  // Scale the original model to 50%.
                        .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.ROOT)
                        .build())
                .setRegistryId(ASSET_URL)
                .build();
```

(2) The following code is to place the 3D object on the image:

```
        if(!modelRenderable.isDone()){
            CompletableFuture.allOf(modelRenderable)
                    .thenAccept((Void aVoid) -> setImage(image))
                    .exceptionally(
                            throwable -> {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Exception loading", throwable);
                                return null;
                            }
                    );
            return;
        }
```

(3)The following code (which i modified from sceneform sample augmentedImage) generate 3D object from static local asset which works with code (2)

```
//        modelRenderable = ModelRenderable.builder()
//                .setSource(context,Uri.parse("SubstanceMiku.sfb"))
//                .build();
```

Error that i'm getting

```
E/Filament: Panic
    in filament::Material *filament::Material::Builder::build(filament::Engine &):85
    reason: Material version mismatch. Expected 2 but received 1.
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 16333 (tapp.cloudimage), pid 16333 (tapp.cloudimage)
I/native: tracking.cc:3027 no history. confidence : 1.0
I/native: tracking.cc:3027 no history. confidence : 1.0
I/native: motion_analysis_calculator.cc:611 Analyzed frame 101
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and after some debugging and searching it appeared to be related to the scenefrom plugin class path.

If you go to the project level grade build file and update the scene form plugin class path to the latest version, synch and try again, this removed the error for me.

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.15.0' // <-- *THIS LINE*

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

As an aside, debugging was tricky, possibly because some functions like ModelRenderable.builder leverage lower layers which do not crash and throw exceptions as cleanly as some of the other Android layers. Even though the crash was being generated from .build within builder, confirmed by commenting out code step by step, the 'exceptionally' clause was not being called.